# MVC: how my application will suffer, if i will get data transfer layer, not by dependency injection, but with singleton, accessed from everywhere?

Tags: dependency-injection

Initial problem:
I had application that injected data transfer layers in controllers and did some business logic there. I decided to refactor it - move all business logic from controllers to models. I ended up transforming DTO objects in Action records.

Current problem:
Action record methods (like FindByKey() or IsExists()) use data transfer layer, that is passed down from controllers. Data transfer layer is same object. So I have a lot methods like

```
...
User user = User.FindByKey(dataTransferLayer, key);
...
if(User.ExistsWithKey(dataTransferLayer, key))
...
```

You can see that all of them have to get `dataTransferLayer`. So, I decided to get it not by dependency injection, but by Singleton, that every class from application can access. So question is "How my application will suffer, if i will get data transfer layer,not by dependency injection in controllers, but with singleton, accessed from everywhere?"

Comment: That's a hard question to anwer, because it depends on the size and lifetime of your application. However, it is important to realize that a design like this violates the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and the Active Record pattern is considered to be [an anti-pattern](http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-1-active-record/).

Answer (score 0):

Using singleton(anti pattern) is not recommended as you may not be able to write unit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Does dataTransferLayer have only business logic, or does it have state also. If it does not have state and has only business logic move all that logic in a helper class and access that logic statically through the helper class, if for some reason its state is important then use a singleton but ensure thread safety since your object is mutable thread safety could be a issue with changes made by one thread to your object reflecting in other threads thus potentially disrupting the business logic.